# How to Find the Global Minimum and Maximum of this Multivariable Function?

Tags: calculus, analysis, special-functions

> We have the set $$M=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb R^3: x^2 + y^2 = z \wedge x+y+z=12\}$$ and the function $$F(x,y,z) = xy+ z^2.$$

***How can we find the global maximum and global minimum of F on M and prove their existence?***

I tried to use Lagrange multipliers:

> $$G(x,y,z)=F(x,y,z)-\lambda_1 m_1(x,y,z)-\lambda_2 m_2(x,y,z)$$
>
> $$G(x,y,z)=xy+ z^2 -\lambda_1 (\ x^2 + y^2-z)-\lambda_2(x+y+z-12)$$

and then  I counted the first partial derivatives of $G(x,y,z)$ by $x$, $y$, and $z$.

I don't know how to continue from this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you consider that the locus of the constraints $ \ M \ $ is the intersection of an "upward-opening" circular paraboloid and an oblique plane, said plane being symmetrical about the plane $ \ y \ = \ x \ $ and sloping "downward" in the "positive" direction, then the constraint curve is a tilted ellipse with its "high end" in the third quadrant of the $ \ xy- $ plane and its "low end" in the first quadrant.  Since the function $ \ F (x, \ y, \ z) \ $ has symmetry about the same plane, we might already guess that the global maximum lies at the high end of the ellipse and that since the product $ \ xy \ $ is negative in the second and fourth quadrants, the global minimum is *likely* be somewhere on the ellipse in each of those quadrants (again by symmetry of the curve and the function).

So saying, the *two*-constraint form of the "Lagrange equations" is

$$ y \ = \ 2 \ \lambda \ x \ + \ \mu \ \ , \ \ x \ = \ 2 \ \lambda \ y \ + \ \mu \ \ , \ \ 2 \ z \ = \  -\lambda \  + \ \mu \ \ . $$

We can immediately "eliminate" $ \ \mu \ $ by writing the single equation

$$ \mu \ \ = \ \ y \ - \ 2 \ \lambda \ x \ \ = \ \ x \ - \ 2 \ \lambda \ y \ \ = \ \ 2 \ z \ + \  \lambda \ \ . $$

(It is the symmetries mentioned above that are permitting us to do this.  The algebra encountered in extremization problems isn't always this obliging.)

We can re-arrange the first pair of terms as

$$ x \ ( \ 1 \ + \ 2 \ \lambda \ ) \ \ = \ \ y \ ( \ 1 \ + \ 2 \ \lambda \ ) \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ ( \ x \ - \ y \ ) \ ( \ 1 \ + \ 2 \ \lambda \ ) \ \ = \ \  0 \ \ . $$

So we see that same $ \ x \ - \ y \ $ factor cropping up that **Kf-Sansoo** shows, which means we want to check values of $ \ F \ $ at the ends of the ellipse where $ \ x \ = \ y \ $ .  (As to where that is, use this in the constraints and solve the system $ \ 2 \ x^2 \ = \ z \ \ , \ \  2 \ x \ = \ 12 \ - \ z \ $ . )

As to the other factor, which gives $ \ \lambda \ = \ - \frac{1}{2} \ $ , we need to see where it goes.  Now we require $ \ x \ \neq \ y \ $ in our " $ \mu  $ " equation:

$$  y \ - \ 2 \ \left( - \frac{1}{2} \right) \ x \ \ = \ \ x \ - \ 2 \left( - \frac{1}{2} \right) \ y \ \ = \ \ 2 \ z \ + \  \left( - \frac{1}{2} \right) \ \ , $$

part of which is redundant.  We now find  $ \ x \ + \  y \ \ = \ \ 2 \ z \  - \frac{1}{2}  \  $ , which can be inserted into the second (linear) constraint equation to find $ \ z \ $  , and these results can be used with the first constraint to find $ \ x \ $ and $ \ y \ $ (we will find two points for this value of $ \ z \ $ , lying in the plane $ \ y \ = \ -x \ $ , again as expected from the geometrical situation.)

[**ADDENDUM:** In checking things over, I went *all* the way through to the end and found that there are no solutions under this second condition -- check for yourself why this is so.  Thus the two points found for $ \ x \ = \ y \ $ are the global extrema.]

Comment: And please can you explain me how to show that M is a compact space ?

Comment: I am supposing you are asking this to prove that these _are_ global extrema.  (I haven't usually had to worry about this.)  My understanding is that a closed and bounded subset of Euclidean space is compact (Heine-Borel).  The intersection curve $ \ M \ $  is the projection of the circle $ \ x^2 + x + y^2 + y \ = \ 12 \ $ onto the tilted plane $ \ x + y + z \ = \ 12 \ $ , so it is certainly bounded.  The complement of $ \ M \ $ is the union of the portions of the plane "exterior" and "interior" to the curve, both of which are open sets; so $ \ M \ $ is also closed.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**: $g(x,y) =x+y+x^2+y^2 = 12\implies xy + z^2 = xy + (12-x-y)^2= 3xy + 144+x^2+y^2-24(x+y)=3xy+144+12-25(x+y)=3xy-25(x+y)+156= f(x,y)$. Thus we have:

$\nabla f = \lambda \nabla g\implies 3y-25 = \lambda(1+2x), 3x-25=\lambda(1+2y)\implies 3(y-x) = 2\lambda(x-y)\implies x = y$ or $\lambda = -\dfrac{3}{2}$. Can you continue from here?